# Get rid of drop down month menu on jQuery UI Datepicker

Tags: jquery-ui, jquery-ui-datepicker

[image]

Im trying to get rid of the drop down menu here (circled in red) and have just display the month (circled in green)

Here is my code for the datepicker so far:

```js
  <script>
    $(function() {
      $( "#from" ).datepicker({
        defaultDate: "+1w",
        changeMonth: true,
        numberOfMonths: 2,
        onClose: function( selectedDate ) {
          $( "#to" ).datepicker( "option", "minDate", selectedDate );
        }
      });
      $( "#to" ).datepicker({
        defaultDate: "+1w",
        changeMonth: true,
        numberOfMonths: 2,
        onClose: function( selectedDate ) {
          $( "#from" ).datepicker( "option", "maxDate", selectedDate );
        }
      });
    });

  </script>
```

```html
  <label for="from">From</label>
  <input type="text" id="from" name="from">
  <label for="to">to</label>
  <input type="text" id="to" name="to">
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Get rid of `changeMonth: true,`.

**[jsFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/t0o6b6f3/1)**

Comment: I am so embarassed... I l thought that disabled the ability to go forward and backward with the months, I should've at least tried it before posting, sorry for wasting your time